# Preemptible kernel can be preemptible during disable interrupts?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

If i disable the interrupts, the kernel can be preemptible (for a single-core processor) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a kernel is preemptible is a general property of the code base. A preemptible kernel doesn't stop being preemptible just because interrupts were disabled to protect a critical region.

Obviously, it's not preemptible while that interrupt-disabled critical region is executing.

Non-preemptible kernels take interrupts (i.e. have them enabled most of the time) while executing kernel code; they just do not allow interrupt-driven switching to a different task while kernel code is executing.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not preemptible while that interrupt-disabled critical region is executing? @Kaz

Comment: It's because the execution of that code cannot be interrupted. Nothing else can happen other than that code finishing its execution to the point where it enables interrupts again. Preemption requires an interrupt to be handled, in such a way that the scheduler chooses a different task  that will execute when the interrupt service routine returns from the interrupt.  (If an interrupt returns to the original task that was interrupted, no preemption has taken place: non-preemptible kernels ensure this is always the case when kernel code is interrupted.)